# how checking a element exists or no with javaScript?

Tags: android

I want to use javaScript inside Android.
I'm going to review after page load
Whether there is a Special tags, or not?
If there is to show the message "yes"
else showing message "no";

```
       web.loadUrl("my_url");

    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                 web.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('Special_id');");
     if(){
             //if special_id exists showing toast.....yes
        }
       else{
        }

    });
```

I do not know how you should  do it(exists tag or no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to check if the element is null, you will need to add a Javascript interface so that the page's Javascript can pass the element back to Java. You can define a Javascript interface in the same activity or fragment that you are using to manipulate the Webview:

```
public class JSInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void setElement(String element) {
        Log.i(TAG, "-----setElement");
        if(element != null){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Object is not null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else{
            Log.i(TAG, "-----NULL");
        }
    }
}
```

You can check if an element with the id 'Special_id' exists by adding the following to your activity or fragment:

```
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsObject, "JSInterface");
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:var element = document.getElementById('Special_id');JSInterface.setElement(element);");
        }
    });
```

The page will call the method in your Javascript interface, passing in the element so that you can check if it is null.

Comment: wow ..thanks a lot of..but in order that I   understand that a element is none or block .What do I need to change the code?

Comment: You can check if the element's display value is block or none by adding this to your Javascript in the webview:  `webView.loadUrl("javascript:var element = document.getElementById('Special_id').style.display;JSInterface.setElement(element);");` Note that the display must be set in css in order to get a value back. Otherwise, you will just get an empty string.

Comment: dont work ..when use Style.display.dont show toast and dont show log in log cat..Can not run the function (setElement) body

Comment: At that point there may be a Javascript issue going on. You may want to ask a question tagged only with Javascript in Stack Overflow.